# 2 stacked divs in container: one shrinks to fit its content, the other expands to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwhyv0ka/6/) containing basic html and css for what I'm trying to do.

Here is my html:

```css
#mother {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

#header,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="mother">
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="title">
    Title content of indeterminate length
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    Main body content of indeterminate length
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a website which will fill 100% of the window height and no more.

The layout needs to consist of 4 sections: 
- header
- title
- main
- footer

The header and footer have a fixed height. The title and main will have content of unknown length.

My ideal behaviour would be for the title container to shrink to fit its content, and the main container to expand to fill the remaining available space before the footer. There will be divs within the main container which will need to be sized to 100% of its height.

The use of absolutely positioned elements or tables is acceptable as long as it has IE support (only need to support most recent version, but support for older versions would be amazing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Flexbox. 
The `flex:1` means it will fill as much space as it can. So leaving the title without `flex:1` allows it to shrink to fit its content.

Also, don't forget to use all the prefixes required for your browser support.

http://shouldiprefix.com/

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwhyv0ka/7/)

```
html, body{

  height:100%;

}

#mother {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
  display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  flex-direction:column;
}

#header, #footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
  flex:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc in css3. 
Include title in main and give height to main content using calc .

```
    #main{
     height: calc(100% - 40px);
    }
```

Title and the inner content should place inside the main.

Comment: Surely then I would have the same problem inside the main container - How to make the inner content take up the remaining space after the title?

Comment: if title have a specific height, then you can use the same.

Comment: My title does not have a fixed height, as specified in the initial question: "The header and footer have a fixed height. The title and main will have content of unknown length."

Comment: may be you can use flex property for this.